# encode dataframe before storing to s3

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, amazon-s3, encoding

I'm using Python's boto3 library to store a .csv file in an S3 bucket. However, the data in the .csv file is changing. I've tried encoding it, but it still appears as shown in the Output.csv image.

For eg.

Input file .csv:

```
Route ID
SOK Cement plant - ISMAILIA-ISMAILIA_001E - EGCAIS0001_100710536_القناة للمواني و المشروعات الكبرى EGCAIS0001
SOK Cement plant - DAMIETA-DAMIETA_001E - EGEDDA0001_C081E_دمياط EGEDDA0001
SOK Cement plant - SUEZ-SUEZ_001E - EGCASU0035_101600411_كروز للتجارة - عتاقه EGCASU0035
SOK Cement plant - SUEZ-EIN SOKHNA_001E - EGCASU0036_101340099_يوني مكس - ميناء السخنة EGCASU0036
```

Output file .csv: after storing s3 using stringIO

```
Route ID
SOK Cement plant - SUEZ-EIN SOKHNA_001E - EGCASU0036_101340099_ÙŠÙˆÙ†ÙŠ Ù…ÙƒØ³  - Ù…ÙŠÙ†Ø§Ø¡ Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø®Ù†Ø©  EGCASU0036
SOK Cement plant - DAMIETA-DAMIETA_001E - EGEDDA0001_C081E_Ø¯Ù…ÙŠØ§Ø·  EGEDDA0001
SOK Cement plant - SUEZ-SUEZ_001E - EGCASU0035_101600411_ÙƒØ±ÙˆØ² Ù„Ù„ØªØ¬Ø§Ø±Ø© - Ø¹ØªØ§Ù‚Ù‡  EGCASU0035
SOK Cement plant - ISMAILIA-ISMAILIA_001E - EGCAIS0001_100710536_Ø§Ù„Ù‚Ù†Ø§Ø© Ù„Ù„Ù…ÙˆØ§Ù†ÙŠ Ùˆ Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø´Ø±ÙˆØ¹Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„ÙƒØ¨Ø±Ù‰  EGCAIS0001
```

I have written below code:

```
final_SC_Result = calculatedRoutes[["Route ID", "Origin", "Destination"]]

final_SC_Result_encoded = final_SC_Result.applymap(lambda x: x.encode('utf-16').decode('utf-16') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
     ShouldCost.objects.filter(should_cost_name=should_cost_name).update(lock_result=True,user_id=user_id)
                csv_buffer = StringIO()
                final_SC_Result_encoded.to_csv('final_SC_Result.csv',index=False)
                #final_SC_Result.to_csv('final_SC_Result.csv', encoding="UTF-8", index=False)
                final_SC_Result.to_csv(csv_buffer, encoding="UTF-8", index=False)
                bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
                folder_name = 'all_data/output/'
                file_name = f"""Final_op_{should_cost_name}.csv"""
                final_op_filename = folder_name + file_name
                s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
                s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, final_op_filename).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I attempted encoding with 'utf-8' and 'utf-16', but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: How are you viewing the CSV?  Have you tried loading it with "utf-8" specified as the encoding?  Have you tried encoding it with "utf-8-sig"?

Comment: Hi @AnonCoward thanks for the reply. I have tried encoding with utf-8 and utf-16. not with utf-8-sig.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'دمياط'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Ø¯Ù…ÙŠØ§Ø·'` (Arabic text from the 2nd line).